# H2O-3 AI Cannot Import Model from Google Cloud Storage to Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, h2o, gcsfuse

I've been trying to run a saved H2O models on Google H2O Cluster for the past few days.

I was able to deploy and connect to the cluster using this guide
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cloud-integration/google-compute.html

```
h2o.cluster().show_status()
```

> H2O_cluster_uptime:    4 hours 38 mins
> H2O_cluster_timezone:  Etc/UTC
> H2O_data_parsing_timezone: UTC
> H2O_cluster_version:   3.32.1.2
> H2O_cluster_version_age:   12 days
> H2O_cluster_name:  root
> H2O_cluster_total_nodes:   1
> H2O_cluster_free_memory:   6.220 Gb
> H2O_cluster_total_cores:   2
> H2O_cluster_allowed_cores: 2
> H2O_cluster_status:    locked, healthy

I uploaded saved model on to Google Cloud Storage and fuse to the VM using Cloud Storage FUSE to this folder

> /tmp/gcsModels/

Now, whenever I try to load the model using .load_model:

```
models_path = "/tmp/gcsModels/serverless/v1/"
pca_model = h2o.load_model(os.path.join(models_path, "cust_PCA_DEMO_v1"))
```

I encounter this error:

```
H2OResponseError: Server error water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException:
  Error: Illegal argument: dir of function: importModel: water.api.FSIOException: FS IO Failure: 
 accessed path : file:/tmp/gcsModels/serverless/v1/cust_PCA_DEMO_v1 msg: File not found
  Request: POST /99/Models.bin/
    data: {'dir': '/tmp/gcsModels/serverless/v1/cust_PCA_DEMO_v1'}
```

Upon checking, the models file are all in the /tmp/gcsModels folder

```
ls /tmp/gcsModels/serverless/v1/
```

> cust_GBM_DEMO_LIKELIHOOD_v2
> cust_GBM_DEMO_LIKELIHOOD_v2_cv5
> cust_GBM_DEMO_LOGAMOUNT_v1_cv5
> cust_PCA_DEMO_v1

I have no idea what I did wrong. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Python client may be hosted at a different location than your H2O server. When you connect with `h2o.connect(url="https://[external ip]:54321", auth=(username, password))`, you are specifying an external IP address. So what you see with `ls` will be at a different location.

Your error message shows that the file is not found on the file system that Python is running at:

```
accessed path : file:/tmp/gcsModels/serverless/v1/cust_PCA_DEMO_v1 msg: File not found.
```

Try using [`gs://` to specify that the file location will be on Google Storage](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html#google-cloud-storage-connector-for-hadoop-spark). I can't tell what your exact path is, but I would expect it something like:

```
h2o.load_model("gs://<BUCKETNAME>/gcsModels/serverless/v1/cust_PCA_DEMO_v1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to import the model with the gs path. I should have been more clear, the ls code was run on the VM running the H2O cluster on GCP – so the file was there but I don't know why H2O couldn't load the model.